# Pattern matching in java with different pattern sets

Tags: java, string

I am trying to specify a pattern matching criteria in java for 2 set of filenames.One that begins like 1PRW12345 or 2PRZ32145 and other  set with SCA1W or SB1FC or any variant that starts with S and has a 5 character limit size

Essentially one of them has been handled like below,how do i open up for other set of files that starts with S alphabet and has 5 characters in them like mentioned above to the existing pattern matching string

If the matchfound is true,i will perform a set of operations.But now i want to include S series with 5 characters limit to the existing pattern match,please advise

```
String inputfield="1PRW12345";  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1-2]PR[K-Z]\\d{2}\\d{3}"); 
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputfield); //String inputfield is defined elsewhere in the program
                boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
```

```
String inputfield="1PRW12345";  
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1-2]PR[K-Z]\\d{2}\\d{3}"); 
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputfield); //String inputfield is defined elsewhere in the program
                boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
```

Comment: I added this condition to the filter of pattern matching,seemed to be working can anyone verify if its accurate:
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[1-2]PR[K-Z]\\d{2}\\d{3}|S[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}");

Comment: that does look accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The way the question is phrased makes it hard to see what the requirements are. Are you just looking for help with creating another pattern which matches your second set of files? If so, you could use `Pattern.compile("S.{4}")`.

Comment: Yes you got it right,managed to add another pattern just like this 
("[1-2]PR[K-Z]\\d{2}\\d{3}|S[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}");

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following pattern, to your current pattern using the `|` specifier.
The `|` is equivalent to implying an "or" condition; e.g., `A|B` = A or B.

```
S.{4}
```

So the full pattern will be the following.

```
[12]PR[K-Z]\d{5}|S.{4}
```

Furthermore, you can simplify your code to a `String.matches` call, which is equivalent to your current code, it does the same thing.

```java
boolean matchFound = inputfield.matches("[12]PR[K-Z]\\d{5}|S.{4}");
```